# How to do an unit test to check if the snack bar is open

Tags: angular, unit-testing, angular-material

I am new to angular and especially on unit testing.

Recently I have been doing a component to use the Mat-Snack-Bar material from angular material (https://material.angular.io/components/snack-bar/overview).

After creating my component, I am working on doing unit testing on this component to check if the class to open the snack bar is called.

I already tried to apply some answers that I found on stack overflow but I couldn't make work my unit testing and I constantly have this error message on the Karma app :

'TypeError: Cannot read property 'openSnackBar' of undefined'

I can't understand what is going bad in my spec.ts of my component and how to fix this error.

My component.ts :

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { MatSnackBar ,MatSnackBarHorizontalPosition, MatSnackBarVerticalPosition, } from "@angular/material";

@Component({
  selector: 'app-snack-bar',
  templateUrl: './snack-bar.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./snack-bar.component.scss']
})
export class SnackBarComponent implements OnInit {

  ngOnInit() {
  }

  constructor(public snackBar: MatSnackBar) {}
  // Position of the snackbar
  horizontalPosition: MatSnackBarHorizontalPosition = 'right';
  verticalPosition: MatSnackBarVerticalPosition = 'top';

/**
 * To use a snackbar add the function openSnackBar('','','')
 * @param message Message that will be shown when the SnackBar is called
 * @param action The message that will be shown on the action button
 * @param state Permit to change the style of the SnackBar depending on the state
 */

  openSnackBar(message: string, action: string, state: string) {
    if ( state == 'suc') {
      var styleOfSnack = 'sucessSnackbar';
    } else if ( state == 'err') {
      var styleOfSnack = 'errorSnackbar';
    } else if ( state == 'inf') {
      var styleOfSnack = 'infoSnackbar';
    } else if ( state == 'war') {
      var styleOfSnack = 'warningSnackbar';
    }
    // code linked to the snackbar
    this.snackBar.open(message, action, {
      duration: 8000,
      panelClass: [styleOfSnack],
      horizontalPosition: this.horizontalPosition,
      verticalPosition: this.verticalPosition,
    });
  }
}
```

'''

And this is my component.spec.ts that verify the code :

```
  describe('SnackBar should be open', () => {
  let component: SnackBarComponent;
  let a = "";
  let b = "";
  let c = "";

  beforeEach(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      declarations: [ SnackBarComponent],
      providers: [ MatSnackBar, Overlay ]
    })
    .compileComponents();
    a = "Test";
    b = "X";
    c = "suc";
  });

  afterEach(() => {
    a = "";
    b = "";
    c = "";
  });

  it('opens', () => {
    expect(component.openSnackBar(a,b,c)).toHaveBeenCalled;
  });
})
```

I expect the unit test to check if the function openSnackBar is called!

Thank you for taking the time to read my issue, if you have any tips or tutorial to understand unit testing on angular for beginners I am taking them!

Comment: In actual component, where are you calling openSnackBar function?

Comment: I should be using it in my HTML code with the attribute (click) : `<button (click)="openSnackBar('Sucess', 'Ok', 'suc')>Test</button> `.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You didn't initialize the component.

```ts
  beforeEach(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      declarations: [ SnackBarComponent],
      providers: [ MatSnackBar, Overlay ]
    })
    .compileComponents();
    a = "Test";
    b = "X";
    c = "suc";
    component = TestBed.get(SnackBarComponent);
  });
```

And you didn't call `toHaveBeenCalled` function.

```ts
  it('opens', () => {
    expect(component.openSnackBar(a,b,c)).toHaveBeenCalled();
  });
```

Comment: Hello, thank you for your help but I still have some issues to do my unit testing, do you have any working example or tutorial to provide so I can complete my unit test? Thank you

Comment: Test document in Angular official web site would be helpful. https://angular.io/guide/testing